# How to concatenate button id with binded values in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is My div tag

```
<div id="generate">    
</div>
```

My dynamically generated html has input type button control which I had bind with unique message id so I can differentiate the button id while clicking .

```
<input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/>
```

This is the detailed code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var generateHere = document.getElementById("generate");
            debugger;
            generateHere.innerHTML = '<div class="card w-post"> <div class="alert alert-danger hide" id="AlertDiv" runat="server"> <asp:Label ID="ErrorMessageLabel" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text=""></asp:Label></div><div class="card-body"><textarea class="wp-text auto-size" id="TextBox1" placeholder="Write Something..."></textarea><div class="tab-content p-0"></div><div class="wp-actions clearfix"><div class="wpa-media-list pull-left"></div> <input type="button" onclick="SaveMessageRecord(); return false" class="btn" value="Post" id="btnInsertRecord"/> </div> </div> </div><div id="result"><div id="hello"><div id="Div1"><div class="card w-item"><div class="card-header"> <div class="media"><div class="pull-left"><img class="avatar-img" src="img/profile-pics/ACER.gif" alt=""/></div><div class="media-body" id="usernames"><h2><%#Eval("username")%></h2><small><%#Eval("posteddate")%></small><h5 id="msgids"><%#Eval("id")%></h5></div> </div></div><div class="card-body card-padding"><p><%#Eval("message") %></p><div class="wis-numbers"><span><i class="zmdi zmdi-comments"></i></span></div><div class="wi-stats clearfix"><div></div></div></div><div class="wi-comments"><div class="list-group" id="result2"><div class="list-group-item media"><div class="pull-right"> </div> <div class="media-body" id="welcome"> <a href="#" class="lgi-heading"><small class="c-gray m-l-10"></small></a><small class="lgi-text"><%#Eval("comments")%></small></div></div></div><div class="wic-form" id="commentsform"><textarea class="wp-text auto-size" data-ma-action="wall-comment-open"  id="TextBox1" placeholder="Write Comments..."></textarea><div class="wicf-actions text-right"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-link" data-ma-action="wall-comment-close">Cancel</button><input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';            
        });
```

Now for cloning div tag I used

```
  $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "RepeaterAjax.aspx/GetMessages",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });


        function OnSuccess(response) {
            debugger;
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);

            var welcome = xml.find("Table");
            var table = $("#hello div").eq(0).remove();
            welcome.each(function () {
                debugger;
                var welcome = $(this);
                var msgid = $("h5", table).html(welcome.find("id").text());
                $("p", table).html(welcome.find("message").text());
                $("h2", table).html(welcome.find("username").text());
                $("#usernames small", table).html(welcome.find("posteddate").text());
                $("h5", table).html(welcome.find("id").text());
                $("#commentsform input[type=button]", table).html(welcome.find("id").text());              
                $("#hello").prepend(table).prepend("<br/>");
                table = $("#hello div").eq(0).clone(true);                
            });
        }
```

My problem is that I can't get dynamic generated button concatenated with msgid which is unique. So while clicking I can differentiate the div generated..

Comment: `welcome.find("id").text()` - are you expecting this to find the button id? It won't, it'll look for an element `<id>`

Comment: as ADyson said instead use doucment.getElementById();

Comment: My query is how can i bind  id  which is found in details code above like   <h5 id="msgids"><%#Eval("id")%></h5>  which is unique and generated at runtime by  $("h5", table).html(welcome.find("id").text());   to <input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/>  .To put it clearly ,each time message is inserted where dynamic div is created ..Inside the dynamic div a button is rendered...I want the button id to bind unique id .So button id can be unique and identifying dynamically generated div and retrieving values is easy ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you give your button a css class unique to that particular button in the dynamic output. Since in the .each you are only ever dealing with one single repetition of the output, there'll only be one button with that class within that section, you can guarantee to find it without knowing the specific id. So if your button now looks like this (I've added (`class="specialButton"`):

```
<input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn specialButton" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/>
```

Then in the javascript you can change

```
var msgid = $("h5", table).html(welcome.find("id").text());
```

to

```
var msgid = welcome.find(".specialButton").attr("id");
$("h5", table).html(msgid);
```

N.B. I've assumed that writing the ID of the button into the `<h5>` tag was your intention. Your original line of code made no sense, so if that's not your intention please correct me.

This will set the variable

Comment: Hey thanks..I need   msgid that is   var msgid = $("h5", table).html(welcome.find("id").text()); to bind with  button id <input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/>  .Problem is div is dynamically generated..Iam doing cloning of div..My msgid which is binded is unique..So i need that msgid to concatenate with input button id so it will be unique and i can differentiate my div.

Comment: @havin yes you've already said all that above. Perhaps I have misunderstood what you need. Have you tried my solution to see if it works for you? That code should find you the unique id of the button which is returned within the `response` HTML

Comment: @havin ?? your last comment makes no sense. I repeat - have you tried my solution to see if it works?

Comment: Hey thanks and sorry for half edited answer before ..Your solution is not concatenating msgid with button id .For Example i get msgid=1 through var msgid = $("h5", table).html(welcome.find("id").text()); which is binding the value in <h5 id="msgids"><%#Eval("id")%></h5> .I need to concatenate the same id to Button in <input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/> so it should look in viewsource like id=b1 , <input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b1"/>..

Comment: @havin in my solution, `msgid` _is_ the button id. If your button id is "b1" then the result of `welcome.find(".specialButton").attr("id")` will be "b1". Then `$("h5", table).html(msgid);` will print "b1" within the `<h5>` tag. If that's not what you want, then you need to explain it a different way.

Comment: Hey sorry i want it other way round..I want  <input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post" id="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"/>  that is id ="b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"  ..if msgid =1 it should be like <input type="button" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" class="btn" value="Post"  id="b1"/>...I wrote this in above code. $("#commentsform input[type=button]", table).html(welcome.find("id").text()); but msgid one is not concatenating..    I hope you got my question.

Comment: @havin but you are already doing that without any of the javascript code. `"b' +<%#Eval("id")%>'"` will resolve to "b1" assuming that "id" = 1. In that case I don't understand what you need the msgid variable for?

Comment: My application is message board .When i post messages . my div is dynamically generated ..Inside my div there is input button for comments post.Now since this div is cloned it will have same div id and button id..If there are 50 messages posted there will like 50 same div id and 50 button id ..So i need to differentiate div or button to identify the particular div..I have generated msgid inside div so i had to append msgid with button or msgid with div..Iam working on solution by appending msgid with buttonid so buttonid will be different for all div cloned.or second solution appending div....

Comment: Msgid is fetched from db through webmethod and it is unique..If you have any solution how can i identify my div which is cloned having same divid or button id..Now i need to identify the div  for comments posting..hence i thought of concatenating the button with unique message id..I.e msgid=1 which is got from db ,need to concatenated like id =b + msgid or next solution is concatenating with div id .If div id="welcome"  it should be like    div="welcome1(msgid concatenated")

Comment: but the code you posted for the button already has the server-side "eval" which will create a unique button id. I don't think I understand the flow of your code in that case.

Comment: Yes that eval is not binding with msgid.. i have done like this. $("#commentsform input[type=button]", table).html(welcome.find("id").text()); but it is not concatenating with msgid..

Comment: sorry but I give up, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve at all. Also I've already told you that `welcome.find("id").text()` won't find anything, but you seem to be persisting with it. If you can't explain the problem in a more logical way I can't help you any further I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes i also  feel like iam not explaining in more logical way..Sorry for that.For me input button id be should be b1 (here b is concatenated with  unique message id 1).How can i do it ..

Comment: Sorry for late reply..I have created table like msgid (which is identity value) ,messages,posteddate,username..So if i post messages it will generate msgid which is unique in db which is binded in front end through webmethod..So with this msgid i had to do all functionalities like users commenting my post in comment section,editing,deleting my messages  etc..So iam binding this msgid with button id as explained to identify div which is cloned....

Comment: Ok that's useful, but really I meant where is it coming from in terms of actual code? is it included in the `response` variable from the ajax call?

Comment: Yes it is  included in the response variable from the ajax call

Comment: ok, in which variable/property? (e.g. `response.d.msgid` or something??)

Comment: Very sorry for late reply..Too much internet problem.. Ajax call is made in RepeaterAjax.aspx/GetMessages   webmethod where iam looping through dataset  fetching msgid,messages,posteddate data from db   and on success iam binding xml values as described in code written at top..

Comment: so what does the XML look like please?

Comment: <NewDataSet>  <Table>    <id>1</id>    <message>welcome</message>    <username />    <posteddate>2016-08-22T09:54:00+05:30</posteddate>  </Table></NewDataSet>"  Here id denotes MSGID Which is identity value

Comment: ok so `var msgid = welcome.find("id").text();` ought to find it. The problem with your existing code is that you're trying to assign the result of the `.html()` method to `msgid`. But that version of `.html()` doesn't return a value - it's used for setting the html content of an element. That's why I originally told you this line made no sense. http://api.jquery.com/html/